# A few questions on quarks, gluons and the strong force

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-spin, quarks, gluons, color-charge

I wanted to answer for myself some pretty fundamental questions pertaining to the strong interaction, color charge and quarks, but I'm sort of stumbling on a few. So I wanted to find the reason/evidence that for each of the following statements:

1. Quarks are fractionally charged

For this one I would say that because we see Baryons (+1,0) with integer charge, and we also observe through scattering experiments that Baryons are made from 3 quarks, quarks should therefore be fractionally charged...

2. Gluons carry colour charge

I would say gluon self-interactions...

3. There are three quark colours

Two up quarks found in the proton + Pauli exclusion principle?

4. Quarks are spin 1/2 fermions

And not sure!

If anyone could either say whether I'm along the right tracks and if I am, could also help me with my understandign for 4 that would be excellent!

Thank you!

Comment: These should be asked separately and several of them are duplicates. http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60356/how-quark-electric-charge-directly-have-been-measured http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70107/why-do-quarks-have-a-fractional-charge go to (1) and shed some light on (4).

Comment: Other interesting links: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2051/why-do-we-think-there-are-only-three-generations-of-fundamental-particles http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/208584/evidence-for-standard-model-description-of-neutrons http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/160257/how-are-quarks-and-leptons-detected-experimentally  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22124/how-the-nucleon-structure-has-been-identified-experimentally and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Let´s go:

**[1]** From the DIS (Deep Inelastic Scattering) of eletron-proton, we can imagine that the photon exchanged in te process "sees" a **parton** (possible constituent of the proton) **distribuition**.

We can imagine a cross-section of photons and that constituents of the proton. And we can analyze two situations:

From a cross-section of longitudinal (scalar) helicity photons, $\sigma_{s}$ and a cross-section of transverse helicity photons, $\sigma_{t}$  we can stabilish a relation:

$$ \frac{\sigma_{s}}{\sigma_{t}}  $$

And experimentally, we know its values. From the theory, this rate goes to *infinite* if we are talking about a *spinless constituent*, and goes to *zero* (at high frequencies of the scattered photon) for a *spin-half constituent*. 
This is how we know that **quarks are spin-half**. (*this answers 4*)

**[2]** There is a excited state of the proton, called $\Lambda^{++}$. This particle is composed by 3 up quarks. As we know the principle of exclusion, we couldn't have 3 fermions *in the same state* unless there is a additional *degree of freedom* we are not taking into account.

This additional degree of freedom is the Colour charge. But the fact that we need 3 colours (3 kinds of charge) cames from the choice of the gauge group that describes the strong interactions, the **SU(3)**.

And by this very choice, we have a **non-abelian gauge symmetry** wich means that our *gauge bosons* (in this case gluons) interact with each other, because in the non-abelian case:

$$ F_{\mu \nu} = {\partial}_{\mu} A_{\nu} - {\partial}_{\nu} A_{\mu} - iq[A_{\mu},A_{\nu}]    $$

The last term (the *commutator*) of $A_{\mu}$ and $A_{\nu}$ does not vanish and so the Lorentz invariant term in the Lagrangian $ F_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu} $ gives 3-field and 4-field interactions of the gauge bosons. (*this answers 3 and 2*)